# indexhibit backgrounded plugin: change background image to foreground

Tags: html, background-image, indexhibit

I'm using the Backgrounded exhibit style on an indexhibit site.

I understand that when an image thumbnail is clicked, that image becomes the background image.

What I'd like to do is change it so it didn't make the clicked image the background image, but instead created an `<img src ...>` image, so I can maintain the background image I'm using for the whole site and have the clicked image displayed on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the backgrounded plugin and add your feature.